# How can I serialize an AttributedString in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, persistent-storage

Or otherwise save it somehow.
I tried creating a class that inherited from AttributedString and implemented Serializable, but things didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observed, the `AttributedString` class doesn't implement `Serializable` and doesn't provide a no-args constructor.  Thus serialization fails. AFAIK, there is nothing in the Java SE libraries to deal with this (directly).

However, I found a 3rd-party library with a class called [`org.jfree.io.SerialUtilities`](http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/api/org/jfree/io/SerialUtilities.html) that provides methods for serializing and deserializing `AttributedString` objects via `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`.

To use these methods, you typically need to write custom `readObject` and `writeObject` methods for any serializable class that uses these type.  I found some examples here:

- http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.jfree.io.SerialUtilities

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html states the following:

> During deserialization, the fields of non-serializable classes will be
>   initialized using the public or protected no-arg constructor of the
>   class. A no-arg constructor must be accessible to the subclass that is
>   serializable. The fields of serializable subclasses will be restored
>   from the stream.

AttributedString doesn't have a no-arg constructor accessible to an extending subclass, hence deserialization will fail.